# Solving matrix equation $AB = C$ with $B (n\times 1)$ and $C (n\times 1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I am trying to solve a matrix equation such as $AB = C$. The $A$ is the unknown matrix and I must find it. I know that $B$ and  $C$ are $n \times 1$ matrices and so $A$ must be $n \times n$.

I can't use the inverse of B since it doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you want all the matrices $A$ satisfying the equation or just one ?

Comment: All of it @nicomezi

Comment: You have more unknowns than equations in your system. No. of equations is $n$ and number of unknowns is $n^2$. As @G Cab says, you need more columns of $B$ in order to invert.

Comment: There is an infinite number of matrices that send a given vector to another given vector...

Comment: But one can nevertheless find the general form of these matrices. I am going to show it in coming answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let me transcript the excellent answer of @G.Cab in a ''visible'' way.

Let me rewrite the matrix equation under the form: $AV_1=V_2$.

As there are no constraints on $A$ sending any vector to any vector, one can write $AA_1=A_2$ with:

$$A_1:=\left(\begin{array}{l|cccc}
\vdots & * & * & * & *\\
\vdots & * & * & * & *\\
V_1 & * & * & * & *\\
\vdots & * & * & * & *\\
\vdots & * & * & * & *
\end{array}\right) \ \ \text{and} \ \  
A_2:=\left(\begin{array}{l|cccc}
\vdots & * & * & * & *\\
\vdots & * & * & * & *\\
V_2 & * & * & * & *\\
\vdots & * & * & * & *\\
\vdots & * & * & * & *
\end{array}\right) $$
where the entries of the $n \times (n-1)$ right blocks are arbitrary (in a practical way : randomly selected).

Then the general solution to your problem is

$$A=A_2A_1^{-1}$$

under the condition that $A_1$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks Jean, that helps and visualize the concept .

Comment: With pleasure...

Comment: yes, it's very clear. Good collaboration ...

Answer (score 3):

If $B = 0$ and $C \neq 0$ no solutions exist. If $B = C =  0$ any $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is a solution.

So consider the case $B \neq 0.$
Given a $ n \times n$ $A=(a_{ij})$  let $\mathbf{a}$ denote the $n^2 \times 1$ column vector $ (a_{11} \dots a_{1n} \ a_{21} \dots a_{2n} \dots a_{n1} \dots a_{nn})^T.$

$\mathbf{a}$ is uniquely determined by $A$ and vice-versa.

Let $\tilde{\mathbf{B}}$ denote then $ n \times n^2$ matrix 
$\begin{pmatrix}
B^T & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & B^T & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & B^T
\end{pmatrix}.
$

Our problem is equivalent to determining all $\mathbf{a}$ that satisfy 
$$\tilde{\mathbf{B}} \mathbf{a} = C.$$

Note that $B \neq 0$ implies $\texttt{rank}(\tilde{\mathbf{B}}) = n$. To see this let $B=\begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & \dots & b_n\end{pmatrix}^T$ and note that by permuting the columns of $\tilde{\mathbf{B}}$ we get the matrix $\left[ \begin{matrix} b_1 I_n & b_2I_n & \dots &b_nI_n \end{matrix} \right]$ and some $b_i \neq 0.$ This implies the above equation always has a solution when $B \neq 0.$

In the complex case we then get all solutions of $\mathbf{a}$ as $(\tilde{\mathbf{B}})^\dagger C + (I - (\tilde{\mathbf{B}})^\dagger \tilde{\mathbf{B}}) x$ where $x$ is an arbitrary $ n^2 \times 1$ vector and $(\tilde{\mathbf{B}})^\dagger$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of $\tilde{\mathbf{B}}$ .

Comment: @very good : that puts all the parameters into the vector $x$ ! it adds to my knowledge, thanks.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks. In fact, you use the classical transformation $IAB=(B^T\otimes I)vec(A)$ (with Kronecker product $\otimes$ ; I am pretty sure you know it but wanted to simplify the presentation for the OP). One very little thing: why do you say "complex case" ?).

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't know if Moore-Penrose inverse makes sense in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

Put aside of the given $B_1$ column vector other $n-1$ vectors, such that the whole becomes a matrix $B_n$ with $n$ independent vectors, so that $B_n$ is invertible.  Do the same with $C_1$, but in this case you do not need independence. Then $A_n$=$C_n B_n^{-1}$ will give you "all" the matrices such that $A_n B_1=C_1$.
Note: the process applies also in case you have $B$ and $C$ with two, .. ,$n$ columns.

Comment: Very clever! You need to handle the case $B_1=0$, but that is trivial.

Comment: @NP-hard, by definition of matrix product (n row x 1st column ..), so if $A B=C$ then $A B_1=C_1$

Comment: @NP-hard  Given a solution $A$, we can first construct any $B$ as indicated we can then choose the columns of $C$ as $c_i = Ab_i$. So if $A$ is solution a choice of  $B$  and $C$ exist such that $AB = C$. The argument works both ways. (Of course assuming $b \neq 0.$)

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri, yes true but .. then you cannot construct $B$  with the requirement of independence, so somehow the case $B=0$ is implicit.

Comment: I am saddened by the downvote, this is a beautiful solution.

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri I did not downvote. I think I've misunderstood the last sentence.

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri, in fact I do not know who down-voted the answer I gave: critics are well-accepted, but they should be done open face, leaving a note with motivations. However I am providing answers, as my experience allows, just to help others to progress, and don't care about points.

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri I am myself also saddened that some (surely very few) people have the bad habit to downvote almost systematicaly answers that are valuable (and in your case, very valuable) but where they have found a little something which is unorthodox to their eyes/prejudices. And are not brave enough to say that they are downvoters.

Answer (score 1):

For two general matrices $B,C$ of order $m \times n$ (note that in your case $m=n$ and $n=1$) over a field $\mathscr{F}$ the equation is solvable if and only if the row space of $C$ is a subspace of the row space of $B$. If this is the case then you can construct the matrix $A$ using the following:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} C & X \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} B & Y \end{bmatrix}^R,$$ where $X \in M_{m \times (m-r)}(\mathscr{F}), Y \in M_{m \times (m-r)}(\mathscr{F})$ and $\begin{bmatrix} B & Y \end{bmatrix}$ is full row rank.The symbol $R$ indicates a right inverse, and $r$ the rank of $B$.

Further, a matrix $A$ of each possible rank can be constructed by choosing $X$ of rank $$0 \leq \text{r}(X) \leq \min(m-\text{r}(C),m-\text{r}(B))$$ such that R$(X) \cap$ R$(C) = \{0\}$. For a full proof and a worked out example please see [this text, specifically the preliminary section on matrix division](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/290393298_Square-zero_Factorization_of_Matrices). You will see in the text the situation is even more general as the rows of $B$ and $C$ may be different - so the idea is to find a "right-quotient" for any two matrices with the same amount of columns, whenever this is possible. Your question is just a special case.

Maybe I can just mention the basic principle involved...If $B$ is full row rank, it has a right inverse and we can write $A=CB^R$. If $B$ is not full row rank we need the matrix $Y$, which simply consists of columns which are linearly independent from the columns of $B$, and then together with $B$ will create a matrix of full row rank. This ensures that a right inverse exists for the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} B & Y \end{bmatrix}$. If we augment the columns of $B$ we also need to augment the columns of $C$ to keep the multiplication 
$$A\begin{bmatrix} B & Y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} C & X \end{bmatrix}$$
valid: this is the matrix $X$. Now $X$ provides a means to vary the rank of $A$.

In practical terms the matrices $X$ and $Y$ can be calculated by applying elementary row/column reduction on $B$ and $C$ and selecting certain columns from the resulting elementary matrices...there is a fully worked example in the text under section 2.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explicit solution assuming real matrices. 
Assume $B = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & \dots & b_n \end{pmatrix}^T \neq 0.$

Also $\|B\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2 > 0.$

The mapping $A \to AB$ is a linear transformation. The kernel of this transformation is the set of all $n \times n$ matrices $A$ whose rows are orthogonal of $B$, i.e., the kernel consists of all matrices of the form $X\left(I - \dfrac{BB^T}{\|B\|^2}\right)$ where $X$ is an arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix.

It is easy to see $\dfrac{CB^T}{\|B\|^2}$ is a particular solution.

So the set of all solutions consists of matrices of the form $\dfrac{CB^T}{\|B\|^2} + X\left(I - \dfrac{BB^T}{\|B\|^2}\right)$ where $X$ is an arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix.